# Recreating the following table

Tags: tables

I want to recreate the following table:[image]

I spent some time on it but I failed. That's what I tried. But it doesn't look like the image above and there have to better ways than doing the line breaks manually.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\thead{\textbf{{\large Definition}}} & \thead{\textbf{{\large Source}}} \\
\hline
\makecell{A knowledge graph (i) mainly describes real world entities and \\ their interrelations, organized
in a graph, (ii) defines possible \\ classes and relations of entities in a schema, (iii) allows for \\
potentially interrelating arbitrary entities with each other \\ and (iv) covers various topical
domains} &  \makecell{Paulheim []}   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Just use `l` for the second column and `p{some length}` for the first one. `\makecell{}` is unnecessary here. Another way is to use `tabularx` with `X` for the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with `tabularx` and `booktabs` for horizontal rules with somme vertical padding (no bertical rules in this case!). I added the inline enumerating environment from `enumitem` for a consistent layout and a clean code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e, makecell, booktabs}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem} 

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\large\bfseries}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Xl}
\toprule
\thead{Definition} & \thead{Source} \\
\midrule
A knowledge graph \enspace \begin{enumerate*}[label=(\roman*), itemjoin ={,\enspace}, itemjoin*={ and\enspace} ]
\item mainly describes real world entities and their interrelations, organized in a graph
\item defines possible classes and relations of entities in a schema
\item allows for potentially interrelating arbitrary entities with each other
\item covers various topical domains
\end{enumerate*} & Paulheim [] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]